# node_auto_index does not exist

Tags: indexing, neo4j

I have created the data set with some entities like Users, Media and their relationships. My `neo4j.properties` file has auto indexing turned on for both nodes and relationships. I have also added an attribute `'type'` to `node_keys_indexable`. However when I get the following error when running the following queries.

```
START user =node:node_auto_index(fn="Balaji") 
RETURN user.ln

Error: Index `node_auto_index` does not exist
```

I am new to `neo4j`. Appreciate any help.

Thanks and Regards
Balaji

Comment: @Josh the title is specific enough for the topic `neo4j`

Comment: could you please paste your `neo4j.properties` file, and the exact properties names your nodes have? than also please provide us with the output of this neo4j-shell console query: `index --indexes`

Answer (score 6):

did you add the nodes before you configured autoindexing?

Then you have to reindex your nodes, by for instance running a cypher query like this:

```
start n=node(*)
where has(n.type)
set n.type=n.type
```

This works well for small graphs, for larger ones you have to page it.

```
start n=node(*)
with n
skip 25000 limit 25000 
where has(n.type)
set n.type=n.type
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same symptom. The problem was that I had misspelled the name of the index keys in the neo4j config. Check the nodes you have created have properties that match the keys in `neo4j.properties`.