# node_auto_index does not exist exception when exported from Gephi tool

Tags: neo4j, gephi

I imported the nodes and edges csv files into the Gephi tool and exported the DB, and copied that DB into Neo4j.

when i run the Cypher.

```
START n=node:node_auto_index(name="ravi") 
RETURN n
```

its throwing error, i had enabled auto indexing to true in neo4j.properties,how to resolve the problem?

Comment: Have you looked at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15688612/neo4j-configuration-with-gephi) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14865128/node-auto-index-does-not-exist)? If they don't help, can you provide more details, for instance, How did you "copy the DB into Neo4j"? What error is thrown?

Comment: jjaderberg.. i just copied the db file created by gephi into the neo4j data folder..

Comment: And the error? No help from the two linked questions?

Comment: hi jjaderberg..this is the error iam getting..

Index `node_auto_index` does not exist

Comment: node_auto_index only creates an index entry when you add nodes/relationships through neo4j so if you generated a store file from gephi then it wouldn't have had a chance to index anything which would explain what you're seeing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure your `conf/neo4j.properties` to use:

```
# Enable auto-indexing for nodes, default is false
node_auto_indexing=true

# The node property keys to be auto-indexed, if enabled
node_keys_indexable=name
```

And re-index your db, e.g. by paging through the db, start `skip` at 0 and increase it by 50000 for every run:

```
start n=node(*)
where has(n.name)
with n
skip 150000 limit 50000
set n.name = n.name
```

Comment: thanks Hunger..One more doubt, this is the permanent solution for the node_auto_index, when we imported from gephi ?